# Building a SIlverlight Entity Framework application with no data initially

Tags: silverlight, frameworks, entity

I have found many samples and examples of silverlight applications that use EF for their data store. Why is it that every single one uses a database full of data and shows how to edit/save? I'm having problems setting up an application where I (want to) have no data to start with and would like my user to then populate the data store. Everything works fine when data exists but I get into all sorts of null problems when I want to start with no data.

Just saying...

ANyway, my question: Does anyone know of any tutorials that demonstrate code where no data yet exists?

Thanks!

Comment: What null problems are you having?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry for my bad english)

I suppose you are using RIA Services? That's the easiest way to develop an SL app with EF. It should make no diference between having data or not, the RIA Service returns a collection with 0 or more itens, you bind that with a DataGrid and are done. Here is a link with source code of a full aplication, that starts with no data: http://johnpapa.net/wcf-ria-services-hands-on-lab - What is most important to understand is the asynchronous nature of RIA Services. Keep that in mind, take a look and try the code.
If you have more questions, try to be more specific about the exact errors or problems you are facing, it would be easy to others try to help you :)